# Why does crockford create this type of error function in his json_parse function?

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js
In this link, Douglas Crockford creates a json_parse function that consists of a lot of functions within one IIFE. One of the internal functions is the following error throwing function:

```
    error = function (m) {
        throw {
            name: 'SyntaxError',
            message: m,
            at: at,                // the variable he stores his incrementing index
            text: text             // the string from the JSON object
        };
    },
```

I am very interested in this error function because I have never seen an error function written like this. When I test out the error function with a useless input like this:

```
json_parse('{123: 123}');
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/<user>/src/crockford.js:30
            throw {
            ^
SyntaxError: Bad string
```

But if I go back to the original error function and modify the error function by removing the at and text values like this:

```
        error = function (m) {
            throw {
                name: 'SyntaxError',
                message: m
            };
        },
```

I end up with the same error message.

What is the point of adding the index and the input text to the error message if it isn't displayed when there is an error? What am I missing about the structure of his error function, and what is the purpose?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing more of your code.

Comment: So basically you are asking what's the point of throwing an object?

Comment: why are you still using that lib to parse when JSON has been standard for over 5 years?

Comment: I am just studying his source code to learn, and I am curious about what I can take away and implement from his error function

Answer (score 2):

Those properties aren't displayed by the default error handler, but they can be accessed by the code in a `catch` block, or you can view them in the Javascript debugger.